# Using SELECT for columns and results to calculate third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL statement where I'm using a select statement for column 1 and 2. These columns return 2 numbers.

It looks something like this

```
SELECT column1, column2, (SELECT a FROM...) as num1,
  (SELECT b FROM...) as num2, (num1/num2) as num3
```

My problem is when I try to do num3 using num1 and num2 to calculate, I get an error saying num1/num2 aren't columns. How do I use those results to calculate num3?

Comment: You getting error because names of the columns(aliases) will be generating after getting result. So they can be used only in ORDER statement for example

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use outer apply, which is usually better if you have a lot of columns, so you don't have to repeat all of them:

```
SELECT 
  column1, column2,
  n1.a, n2.b, n3.c
FROM table1
outer apply (SELECT a FROM...) as n1
outer apply (SELECT b FROM...) as n2
outer apply (select case when n2.b != 0 then n1.a / n2.b end as c) as n3
```

Added also check for divide by zero. Didn't test this but hopefully it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a subquery which will have num1 and num2 and then calculate num3

```
select T.*, (num1/num2) as num3
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      column1, column2, 
      (SELECT a FROM...) as num1, 
      (SELECT b FROM...) as num2, 
    FROM table1
) T
```